# Colocar estas condiciones en un programa C (básico)

Tags: c, condiciones

¿Cómo puedo poner estas condiciones en C?:

- Que las horas de trabajo totales sean solo positivas.
- Que el nombre y apellido sean solo letras.
- Que la cédula sean solo 10 dígitos.

Éste es el código de mi programa:

```
int main(void){
 char nombre[40]="",apellido[40]="",correo[40]="",direccion[40]="";
 int opcion=0,relacion=0,cedula=0,telefono=0;
 float horas_1=0,horas_2=0,horas=0,descuento=0,adi=0,total=0;
 do{
 system("cls");
 printf("\n***** menu de opciones*****");
 printf("\nBuenas tardes estimado docente, a continuacion le pediremos los siguientes datos");
 printf("\nPara ingresar sus datos personales digite #1 ");
 printf("\nPara revisar su pago por contrato esdigite #2 ");
 printf("\nPara revisar su pago por nombramiento digite #3 ");
 printf("\nPara finalizar el programa digite #4 ");
 printf("\nIngrese su opcion a escoger: ");
 scanf("%d",&opcion);
 switch(opcion){
 case 1:
 system("cls");
 do{
 printf("\ningrese su numero de cedula: ");
         scanf("%d",&cedula);
 }while(cedula<0||cedula>9999999999);
             printf("\nIngrese sus nombres: ");
             scanf("%s%s",&nombre,&apellido);    
             printf("\nIngrese la direecion de su domicilio: ");
             scanf("%s",&direccion);
 printf("\nIngrese su correo electronico: ");
             scanf("%s",&correo);
             printf("\nIngrese su numero de telefono: ");
             scanf("%d",&telefono);
             printf("\n\n");
             system("pause");
     break;
 case 2:
 system("cls");
 printf("\nIngrese sus horas de trabajo: ");
         scanf("%f",&horas);
         horas_2= horas*pago_c;
         printf("\nSubtotal a pagar: %.2f",horas_2);
         descuento=horas_2*seguro_m;
         printf("\nDescuento por seguro medico: %.2f",descuento);
           if(horas>160){
         adi=(horas_2-descuento)+1.885;
             printf("\nEl total a pagar es: %.2f ",adi);
 }else if(horas<=160){
 total=horas_2-descuento;
 printf("\nSu valor total a pagar es: %.2f",total);
 printf("\n\n");
 printf("\nQue tenga un buen dia");
 }
 printf("\n\n");
 system("pause");
     break;
     case 3:
     system("cls");   
          printf("\nIngrese sus horas de trabajo: ");
         scanf("%f",&horas);
 horas_1= horas*pago_n;
 printf("\nSubtotal a pagar: %.2f",horas_1);
 descuento=horas_1*seguro_m2;
 printf("\nDescuento por seguro medico: %.2f",descuento);
 if(horas>160){
 adi=(horas_1-descuento)+2.37;
 printf("\nEl total a pagar es: %.2f ",adi);
     printf("\n\n"); 
 printf("Que tenga un buen dia");
 }else if(horas<=160){
 total=horas_1-descuento;
 printf("\nSu valor total a pagar es: %.2f",total);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\nQue tenga un buen dia");
    }
     printf("\n\n"); 
    system("pause");
    break;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO. Te doy unas recomendaciones 1. Indentar bien el código, te ayudará a ti y a los demás a entenderlo. 2. Nunca utilizar `scanf` para pedir input del usuario, en general evitar todas las funciones `*scanf`, más información en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf). 3. Tu pregunta está bien formulada, describes lo que quieres lograr y pones código con lo que has intentado, pero no creo que esté de más leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, sirve que obtienes tu primera medalla

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También te recomiendo que sigas las recomendaciones de @BenjamínGuzmán,. porque tu código es difícil de seguir debido al mal formato. Un ejemplo podría ser el [código de estilo de Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) y otro el [código de estilo de GNU](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Formatting.html). Con ambos tu código se leerá claramente y será más fácil de entender.